# Nothing found using find function - why it doesn't proceed with the code?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new here and I don't know exactly what I am doing. I have a problem with a find function - if there is nothing found it throws the error 'Object variable or With block variable not set' I've tried if loop, but the debuger doesn't consider them. It crushes on `findFeature = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("featureListLTE").Range("A1:A1000").Find(featureID, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)` line

```
Dim newInput As Long
newInput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("input").Range("A1", ThisWorkbook.Sheets("input").Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To newInput

'find feature on feature list

Dim featureID As String
featureID = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("input").Cells(i, 1).Value
MsgBox featureID

Dim findFeature As Variant
Dim findFeatureRow As Integer

findFeature = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("featureListLTE").Range("A1:A1000").Find(featureID, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

findFeatureRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("featureListLTE").Range("A1:A1000").Find(featureID, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Row

If findFeature.Value Is Nothing Then

MsgBox "nima"

Else: MsgBox findFeatureRow
End If

Next i
```

Comment: `If findFeature.Value Is Nothing Then` Remove `.Value`

Comment: You also can't use `.Row` if there is no result. Put that inside `If Not findFeatureRow Is Nothing Then`

Comment: You don't have to redo the Find to get the row. If findFeature is not nothing, just use `findFeatureRow = findFeature.Row`

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a `.Value` or `.Row` if no range was found. Put them inside a block after checking whether a range was found or not. For example (**untested**), your code can be written as

```
Dim findFeature As Range

Set findFeature = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("featureListLTE").Range("A1:A1000").Find(featureID, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not findFeature Is Nothing Then
    findFeatureRow = findFeature.Row
    MsgBox findFeatureRow
Else
    MsgBox "nima"
End If
```

You may find [.Find and .FindNext](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) interesting to read.

Comment: Thank you, but it still does't work. The debugger stops at the same line with return value FindFeature = Empty

Comment: @Kidakagasz You've got `findFeature` declared as a `Variant` data type. So, without the `Set` keyword, it will pick up the value of the found cell, and not have a `.Row` property.  (Even if it were declared as a `Range`, you'd still need to use the Set keyword, but you'd get an error if you did not).

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: Thanks I missed that :D